# How to implement sales team in salesforce

Tags: user-management

I have a requirement where we would like to implement Salesteam in salesforce.Can any one help me out with your ideas and suggestion what all needs to be done and how it will get processed.Do we have any documents related to Sales Team implementation in salesforce.

For Example : For a project as We have the Project Manager ,Project Lead ,Senior Developer ,Junior Developer etc.

Comment: What is your goal here? Is this for forecasting, for data security, for quotas, for something else entirely? Have you gone through the CRM basics sections on Trailhead? What have you tried, why isn't it working, and what is the context for your need.

Answer (score 0):

for setup a team you need to setup few things.

1. Create different Profile for different access level and grant access to them as per your requirement(Object level, field level, record type).
2. Setup role hierarchy of different levels.
3. Now create user and assign them profile and roles and setup your team. Everyone will get access of their level .
4. For additional permissions use permission set etc.